# change sleep time in knoppix linux

Tags: linux, knoppix

I want to transfer files from one comp to another. Its a few hundred gigs. Since the pc crashed i am using knoppix to access the drive and sharing over samba.

I'm using robocopy to copy the files. But i have a small problem with sleep. Every 30mins or maybe an hour knoppix goes to sleep and my transfer stops. How do i change the time or disable it completely? so i dont have to tap a key every 30mins

Answer (score 0):

Check in the control center / power settings if there is a time set on the sleep action. You can also try passing `apm=off` or `noapm` to the [kernel during startup](http://www.knoppix.net/wiki/Cheat_Codes), turning off advanced power management features.